# Acceptance-rate in PyMC3 (Metropolis-Hastings)

Tags: python, pymc3

Does anyone know how I can see the final acceptance-rate in PyMC3 (Metropolis-Hastings) ? Or in general, how can I see all the information that pymc3.sample() returns ?

Thanks

Comment: Remember to check https://discourse.pymc.io/ for this type of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked for the NUTS algorithm, and found the solution from here [pymc3 forum](https://discourse.pymc.io/t/warning-when-nuts-probability-is-greater-than-acceptance-level/594).

```
trace.mean_tree_accept.mean()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Given an example, first, set up the model:

```
import pymc3 as pm3

sigma = 3 # Note this is the std of our data
data = norm(10,sigma).rvs(100)
mu_prior = 8
sigma_prior = 1.5  # Note this is our prior on the std of mu

plt.hist(data,bins=20)
plt.show()

basic_model = pm3.Model()

with basic_model:
    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    mu = pm3.Normal('Mean of Data',mu_prior,sigma_prior)
    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    data_in = pm3.Normal('Y_obs', mu=mu, sd=sigma, observed=data)
```

Second, perform the simulation:

```
chain_length = 10000 

with basic_model:
    # obtain starting values via MAP
    startvals = pm3.find_MAP(model=basic_model)
    # instantiate sampler
    step = pm3.Metropolis() 
    # draw 5000 posterior samples
    trace = pm3.sample(chain_length, step=step, start=startvals)
```

Using the above example, the acceptance rate can be calculated this way:

```
accept = np.sum(trace['Mean of Data'][1:] != trace['Mean of Data'][:-1])
print("Acceptance Rate: ", accept/trace['Mean of Data'].shape[0])
```

(I found this solution in an online tutorial, but I don't quite understand it.)

Reference: [Introduction to PyMC3](https://rlhick.people.wm.edu/stories/bayesian_7.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let step = pymc3.Metropolis() be our sampler, we can get the final acceptance-rate through

"step.accepted"

Just for beginners (pymc3) like myself, after each variable/obj. put a "." and hit the tab key; you will see some interesting suggestions ;)